# how to enable debug on Galaxy tab 3 running Android kitkat 4.4.2

Tags: android, build-numbers

I know I can go to Settings/about device and tap the build nr 10 times and that will enable Developer options. I Have done this on many devices but on this Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 10.1 the build nr options is grayed out

Here´s a picture(It´s Swedish Language) the "kompileringsnr" is Build Nr

What to do?

[image]

Comment: It does not matter that is grayed out, just tap it 7 times.

Comment: Your right, I have tapped it so many times but suddenly it worked must be the old slow device